# Grouping php array

Tags: php

I have got a following array:

```
$arr = array(
    "nameA" => 10,
    "nameA" => 10,
    "nameB" => 10,
    "nameB" => 10,
    "nameB" => 20
    );
```

What is the shortest way to turn it into this:

```
$arr2 = array(
    "nameA" => 20,
    "nameB" => 40
    );
```

Comment: Your input is invalid. You can't have the same key twice. PHP will ignore the duplicated keys and stay with the last one.

Comment: As @FelippeDuarte said, the array has multiple keys and would erase earlier data leaving you wit nameA=10 and nameB=20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to save data like this, you could use a two dimensional array.

```
$data = array( 
   „nameA“ => array( 10, 20, 30 ),
   „nameB“ => array( 10, 20 )
);
```

To sum the values up:

```
foreach( $data as $d ){
    $d = array_sum( $d );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array(
    "nameA" => 10,
    "nameA" => 10,
    "nameB" => 10,
    "nameB" => 10,
    "nameB" => 20
    );
```

when you declare like this, it will always implicitly have two elements in $arr.
But I don't know what is your purpose for this declaration, why do you sum it at first.